# Facebook Graph API - Is it possible to pass parameters to the redirect uri?

Tags: redirect, facebook-graph-api, parameters

As you probably know, Facebook has introduced a **Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs option** for **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** which is turned on by default.

My requirement is to pass a parameter to the Redirect URI as below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri= 
{redirect_uri?Parameter=parameter}&scope={scope}
```

This used to work but doesn't work anymore as Facebook now string matches the Redirect URI to ensure it's a valid one.

How can this be achieved with the changes put in place by Facebook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#strict_mode:

> For apps with dynamic redirect URIs, **use the state parameter** to pass back the dynamic information to a limited number of redirect URIs. Then add each of the limited redirect URIs to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs list.

(Highlight by me.)

The `state` parameter is the only “dynamic” one, that can have whatever value you like.

But since its purpose is also XSRF protection, you should rather not replace it with a static value or a value from a limited set; I would recommend you keep part of it dynamic - f.e. by passing a data structure that consists of a random value, and the actual value you need to transport, encoded as JSON.

If you are using any library/SDK that automatically performs the XSRF check against the session, then you need to make sure that this combined value is also the one that gets stored into the session.

Comment: Could you please integrate some sample code using the latest "php graph sdk" to better explain the "state" usage integration to transmit dynamic data?